# How to Expand and Collapse the Bootstrap accordion panel as user choice

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How to Expand and Collapse the Bootstrap accordion panel as user choice means if i expand A collapsible panel and after that expand B collapsible panel then A should not collapse. If use want to collapse it then can do by click on the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by having different parents for each collapse

```
  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne"
```

second one

```
     data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo"
```

bootstrap only detects the parent to hide previously opened collapse.

Answer (score 0):

```
           Requirement 1 : To Expand and Collapse the Bootstrap accordion panel as user choice not to auto close, please use the below code.
```

1)  data-parent="#accordian"
Note : will work for auto close of expanded panel while click on another.
2)  data-parent="#proposalAccordian"
Note : will work to stop auto close of accordion panel while click on another.
Requirement 2 : Adding  (-) and (+) symbol while expand and collapse.

1)  Add the following code in the appropriate place . Please refer the attached file to do this .


2)  Also add the following javascript code in the header.

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
            }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
            });
        });